# How to load MultipartFile in Spark with Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to load a csv file which is coming form a post request by getting the name of file like this

```
val df= SparkConfig.sc.read.format("csv")
.schema(TableSchema.getDFSchema()).option("header", "false")
.csv(file.getOriginalFilename)
```

But it is giving path not found error. My question is how to load multipart file in spark.

Answer (score 1):

You need to materialize the file in a local file system before passing it to Spark.

So, first save the `POST`ed file using whatever HTTP framework you're using, grab the location in the local filesystem and use that to call Spark.